# Is getting a Scrum Master Accredited Certification at Scrum Institute worth it?

Tags: scrum, scrum-master, career, certification

I'm being tempted to take the [Scrum Master Accredited Certification at Scrum Institute](https://www.scrum-institute.org/Register_Scrum_Certification_Program.php?utm_source=International%20Scrum%20Institute&utm_campaign=ac6853bb1c-0001%20-%20001%20%2528Welcome%20and%20Books%2529&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_a47ff48ae0-ac6853bb1c-120362457&goal=0_a47ff48ae0-ac6853bb1c-120362457&mc_cid=ac6853bb1c&mc_eid=3396a07bc4). Initially, I was planning to get PRINCE2 certification but then got an advice by a fellow PM that I should get this one as well.

I really don't mind the cost for it, but I just want to know if this one is being recognized/accepted. Also, is there anyone here already took the said certification from them? If yes, what was the reason behind it?

Please note I've already read the following before posting this question:

- [Which Scrum certification provider is most widely recognized or accepted?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/which-scrum-certification-provider-is-most-widely-recognized-or-accepted)
- [Career path in project management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/2165/career-path-in-project-management?rq=1)
- [Is the PMP or other project management certification worth while to have?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/871/is-the-pmp-or-other-project-management-certification-worth-while-to-have?rq=1)

Comment: This is the first time I have heard of "scrum-institute.org". I notice that Peter Egbe has something to say about that site here: https://www.scrum.org/forum/scrum-forum/6314/scrum-master-accredited-certification https://www.scrum.org/ is Ken Schwaber's site. He was one of the inventors of Scrum. https://www.scrumalliance.org/ runs the original Scrum certification programme set up by Ken Schwaber and others.

Comment: @nvogel - actually Ken Schwaber created scrum.org after breaking up with scrumalliance.org. If you're looking for something supported by him, scrum.org is your way to go.

Comment: Seems rather subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Generically speaking, a certificate truly worth it if it passes two tests: 1) the process of certification is challenging enough that it filters out those who are consistently lower performers, and 2) the hiring market trusts and is using the certificate as a criterion in its selection methods.  It is somewhat worth it if test 2 is true because, even though the certificate would be useless as a valid predictor, the market demands it.

Test 2 is largely geographic.  What might be true in one area could be false in another.

So if you want to know the answer to your question, you need to find research to see if there is any finding that certified Scrum people are higher performers than non certified folks, and then you need to scan your market to see if employers and seller of services are requiring the certificate.  Some folks here might be able to answer, and provide sources, for the first part of this research but only you can determine the second part since none of us knows where you live.

Just an aside, I found three or so studies on the efficacy of the PMP certificate and all three generally found no difference in performance between those who held the PMP and the rest of the PM population.  Only three studies but it does not look like the PMP is a valid predictor of performance.

Comment: I think this might be missing a third test of worth: whether the certificate actually teaches you to be better at what it claims to be teaching you about. I've seen some that asked questions so inane that while they were challenging to do, weeded out people low performers, those who held the certificate didn't actually learn anything useful from it. Very little of the knowledge in the exam had any useful application.

Comment: That's what test 1 is. If it is filtering, leaving incompetents behind, then the assumption is the competent ones remaining learned something of value and their performance is on average better than the overall pool. I think I could have explained that better in my answer. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

A certification, any kind of certification, is worth more when you are inexperienced and worth less and less as you gain more experience.

When you are inexperienced, the knowledge you acquire from the certification is worth a lot because you might not have had exposure to it and you learn about it as you get certified. If you are a scrum master with 15 years of experience you probably know a lot more than the knowledge required to pass the certification exam, so the information needed to get certified isn't worth as much because it's stuff you already know, it isn't an investment in something new. Either way though, if you are after the information and the knowledge, you will spend the time to acquire it and it is irrelevant if you get certified or not. So, to you, getting certified is, from this point of view, kind of irrelevant. Sure, passing the actual exam is a validation for you that you understood the information, but you could use test exams to verify the same, without actually spending money on the piece of paper that says you know Scrum.

The question is thus only about that piece of paper that says that you are accredited. It's not about the knowledge, since as a Scrum master you still need to know the stuff that's in there.

The certification becomes important for companies as a selection criteria for new Scrum masters. Is it important all new hires are certified or not? If someone has 15 years of experience and great successes helping Scrum teams, but no certification, is that important? What if someone has 15 years of experience and great successes helping Scrum teams, and a certification, is that even more important?

That's why I said in the beginning that a certification is worth more when you are inexperienced. Because, when companies decide to hire junior Scrum masters for example, and they find a few candidates with similar knowledge and skills, and similar salary demands, the certification might be the decision factor since it might show that candidates that have it are more commited to the Scrum practices and more invested into  becoming better Scrum masters. But that's a belief, not a fact. As others have pointed out, in this post and in the ones you linked, there is no proof that a certification will make you better at your job. 15 years of experience though, might say more about it.

I used to interview a lot of Java developers back in the days where everyone was chasing the SCJP certification, and what I noticed was that the worst candidates were the ones with certifications. I'm not saying I attributed this as the cause, what I'm saying is that the developers that were bad, were bad even after being certified as Java programmers. If you suck at your job, be it Java developer, Scrum master or watever, you will suck with having a certification also. The certification just shows you can study some material then pass an exam. You get more skills from experience and exposure, not exams.

As the other answer here mentions, you need to search within your job market to see if employers are requiring the certificate or not, and if you want to work for them or not, because not having a certification will be an elimination criteria and a disadvantage to you. But then again, if research show no remarkable difference between those with certifications and those without, and from experience people discover (as I did) that they don't make someone suck less, then why are the certifications so important for such companies? Just saying...

Answer (score 1):

Glad that you did your research.

Looking at this site I would strongly discourage any "certification" with them. There is no single name of any renowned expert associated with that site. In fact there is no name at all.

Looks more like a scam site.

I looked at [my answer to original Scrum certification question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/9853/3501) and it seems to still be valid.